# Switch focus between TextFields on hitting Enter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need pressing Enter on a MaterialUI TextField to shift focus to the underlying field. That is, I need it to behave similarly to the Tab key operation.

```
<TextField
    label='Documento'
    name="document"
    autoComplete="document"
    autoFocus
    type='text'
    value={data.document}
    onChange={e => { handleChange(e) }}
    inputProps={{ onKeyDown: handleKeyDown }}
/>

<TextField
    label="Contraseña"
    type="password"
    autoComplete="current-password"
    inputProps={{ onKeyDown: handleKeyDown }}
    onChange={e => { handleChange(e) }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to assign an id to the underlying text field. For example:

```
<TextField
    label="Contraseña"
    type="password"
    autoComplete="current-password"
    inputProps={{ onKeyDown: handleKeyDown }}
    onChange={e => { handleChange(e) }}
    id="text-field-password"
/>
```

Then when defining the `handleKeyDown` function you could check if enter is pressed by checking if the event that triggered the function to execute have a key code of 13. Then, if enter was pressed you could access the underlying text field by the id you gave it and use the `focus` method on the text field. This will change the keyboard focus from the first text field to the second. Similar to the tab key operation. An example of `handleKeyDown` function:

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      document.getElementById("text-field-password").focus()
    }

  }
```

If an `handleKeyDown` function already is defined you could just put the if statement in that function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, at the time I forgot to clarify that I am working with React.js.
Apologies to whoever took the trouble to reply, and thank you @bystrom.

I finally solved this by implementing [React's useRef](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```
const passFieldRef = useRef(null);
```

.

```
<TextField
    id="document"
    label='Identificación'
    name="document"
    value={data.document || ''}
    onChange={handleChange}
    inputProps={{ onKeyDown: handleKeyDown }}
/>

<TextField
    name="password"
    label="Contraseña"
    type="password"
    id="password"
    inputProps={{
        onKeyDown: handleKeyDown,
        ref: passFieldRef
    }}
    value={data.password || ''}
    onChange={e => { handleChange(e) }}
/>
```

Lastly, this is how handleKeyDown was defined, note that the focus change only applies if ENTER is pressed with focus on a particular field (`document`). For the rest, other logic is simply executed.

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    const fieldName = e.target.name;

    if (e.code === "Enter") {
        switch (fieldName) {
            case 'document':
                passFieldRef.current.focus();
                break;
            default:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```